# Button.watch() not watching

Tags: gpio, node.js

I've following [this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/node-embedded-development?view=all#why-node-dot-js)  but using the setup shown below.  I can get my LED working fine, but the `button.watch()` doesn't seem to listen to the button.

When I run [this python script](https://github.com/adafruit/Python-Thermal-Printer/blob/master/main.py) & then rerun my node app `button.watch()` works as expected... so I'm guessing the python script is opening a connection & then it's staying open for the node app to use.

What am I doing wrong that when I first run my node app I can't get `button.watch()` to actually listen to button events?

`node - v4.2.1
 Linux 4.1.13+ #826 PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 20:13:22 GMT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux`

[image]

```
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio,
led = new Gpio(18, 'out'),
button = new Gpio(23, 'in', 'both');
console.log('boot');

led.writeSync(1);
function exit() {
    led.unexport();
    button.unexport();
    process.exit();
}
console.log(
//the value of this is 0 right now
button.readSync()
);

button.watch(function(err, value) {
    //these console.log commands never get fired
    console.log(value);
    led.writeSync(value);
    console.log('button valued changed');

});

setInterval(function(){

    led.writeSync(led.readSync() ^ 1);

}, 1000);

process.on('SIGINT', exit);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I just didn't RTFM.

I'm totally new to hardware & electronics so I'll explain what I did for newbies like I was all of 10 min. ago....

In order for you button to function properly you need to configure a resistor aka a "pull up" or "pull down" via the OS. In my case I needed a "pull up"

[Read this](https://github.com/fivdi/onoff/wiki/Enabling-Pullup-and-Pulldown-Resistors-on-The-Raspberry-Pi) - I mean really read it, don't just skim it. Following these instructions got it working for me.

Comment: Justin, I read it and it did not clear the issue for me. How do you know if your button needs a "pull up" or "pull down" resister? Can you please include here the "tree" you created and what you did with it ? Thx.

Comment: ...In my case I have 3 lights that work on GPIO 14, 15, and 18.  All fine there. I have 3 On-Off buttons on GPIO 2, 3, and 4 that seem non-functional in that the onoff module's watch() function never triggers for any of them.  :(

Comment: From what I understand you should just us a pull up.  Essentially that pin is set with current & when you press your button, it completes the circuit to "ground" & disconnecting the power makes the pi reboot.  So pretty much even once you do a `shutdown` it's not actually powered off.  It goes into low power mode - when you break that current it reboots.  Make sense?

Comment: Using a button as power on only works on GPIO3 I think and maybe a couple other pins that get set to `high` to begin with.  Not sure which they are, like 16 & 18 maybe.  Search for default GPIO values & you should find some info about which pins are set high/low.

Also, you have to use a .dtb file to set your pins as high for on/off to be able to "listen" for a change.

Does that answer your question?